# does Google Visualization send your data to Google?

Tags: charts, visualization

Does Google Visualization, when creating a chart , send your data (the x and y values and labels) back to Google? Or does it create the chart with Javascript in the client?
I mean the HTML5 Google API loaded with this command

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

( https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start ) , not the old Chart API that created an image.

I am concerned about the security of my data, which is internal corporate data I want to present only on our intranet.

Comment: Why not try it and see? Watch network requests while the chart is constructed.

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/security_privacy

They claim that the data is kept only a short time for debugging purposes, then deleted. However if this is legally protected data under HIPA or SEC regulations that is unlikely to be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

After reading further I found these on Google saying that for many charts, no data is sent to Google (or even your own server).

"All Google-authored charts are developed with privacy and security considerations in mind. All Google chart documentation pages include a data policy section that describes whether a chart sends any chart data from the page."

Line Chart: All code and data are processed and rendered in the browser. No data is sent to any server. 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Data_Policy

Scatter Chart - same
Area Chart - same